# give 10 different text loaders for every time someone loads a page in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am creating a loading page with message, and create a demo as that loading page with text and
i want to show per loading show different text message, and i have try much time like creating araay and try in list, but not getting proper

my code is

```
   {
      loading ?
        <div>
        <img src={stackLoader} width="50px" />
            <p>Loading your stacks..</p>
        </div> 
      : <React.Fragment>
           loading else part
      </React.Fragment>
   }
```

here ,loading is a state variable and i want to show  in paragraph 

Loading your stacks..

   every **loading** new text message **like , hello,stack,workspace** etc...

anybody solve please!

thanks!

Comment: Check this code out https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-hooks-sepzm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get any random loading text, you may want to keep those answers inside of an array, and write a code which will pick a random text from that array and put inside of your p. The code will look something like this:

```
const answers = ['Hello', 'Loading', 'Next'];
const randomAnswer = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
```

then show randomAnswer inside of your p.